# Should program behavior be modified using a config file or environmental variables?

Tags: configuration, configuration-management, command-line, environment

I'm referring to *nix command line applications primarily, where you want to permanently modify the behavior from defaults.

Environmental variables are easily understood and implemented, usually requiring the user to modify their `~/.bashrc` for a permanent change. However, namespace collision might be a problem (but unlikely if you're careful).

On the other hand, a lot of programs use `~/.programrc` config files.

Is it simply verbosity? If your program only has 2 configuration settings, then a simple `export APP_SETTING=1` works just fine. However if you're starting to offer 5+ options then it should be time to start looking into a config file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many other pressures:

- Writing a config file requires write permission on the file system (in fact, it requires a file system in the first place!). Environment variables can be set even if you are running a rescue system from a CD.
- Environment variables can be set quickly and temporarily just for one invocation, which is much better for use in small shell scripts. (Rewriting and re-rewriting a config file risks destroying the original settings if the process doesn't terminate correctly. Temporary values die automatically.)
- A config file can be passed around easily to some other user or pre-installed with a distribution. Telling someone how to use environment variables is much harder. You wouldn't believe how much harder it is to get normal people to type `CDG_VERBOSITY=5 cdg` correctly then just `cdg`.
- Environment variables may or may not get inherited properly if your program farms out work to other processes. A config file is always there.
- There can be surprisingly low limits on the size of the environment that can be passed to a process on some systems. The file system is much, much more forgiving.
- If you need to change settings after program start, telling a process to re-read its config file is a well-known idiom. Changing the environment of a running process can be trickier.
- Reading a config file hits the disk, which is massively slower than reading from the environment. A config file would be grossly inappropriate for something like `grep`, which is usually invoked on data that are entirely in memory.

Comment: To the above list, I would add: Config files can be stored under revision control, so a record can be kept of deployed configuration & configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

Config files (for the sake of keeping a record of configuration changes), overridden by (optional) environment variables (for the sake of temporary modifications in uncontrolled environments).